# Semicolon in SELECT query

Tags: sql-server

I cannot find documentation about the usage of semi-colons in a select query, for example:

```
SELECT TEST.PARTIAL_PATH + ';' + G.ICON FROM GADGETS G 
.... some inner joins...
```

Can somebody point to the documentation that gives some examples or try to explain it here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just concatenating a semicolon between two fields. Think of it like selecting `LNAME + ', ' + FNAME` or something similar.

It's generally fine to have presentation layer items like this in the select list, but it's important to avoid them as predicates (anything in a join or where clause), because in SQL Server, they're not [SARGable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable).

SQL Server uses `+`, which is *different* from other platforms, that may use `||` to concatenate things, which is an issue I've [written about](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/08/week-fix-change/) in the past.